# I am looking for a way to map input from a bluetooth HID device ( remote shutter ) in Android

Tags: android, btle

I am looking for a way to map the input from a bluetooth remote shutter to a different "keystroke".
The device I am using is one of these cheap bluetooth remote shutters which sends a "Volume Up" command only.
My goal would be to map this to media key Start / Stop.

Any help greatly appreciated